# Converting String to Double in Swift reveals extra decimal places

Tags: swift, string, format, double, rounding

I am trying to round a number to 7 decimal places by converting my input number to a string and then back to a double. The value of the string is how I would like it, but when converting it back to a double more decimal places are revealed. Any remedy for this situation?

```
let inputNumber: Double = 99.99990338164251

let roundedString = String(format: "%.7f", inputNumber) //"99.9999034"

let outputNumber = Double(roundedString) //99.99990339999999
```

Comment: You can use NSNumberFormatter when displaying your float to the user. If you need more precision you can use Swift Decimal type

Answer (score 0):

Use `Decimal` class instead of `Double`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal

You problem is a common for floating number calculations

More detailed for ObjC class https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber